# Python 3 Curses Terminal Tetris

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, object-oriented, tetris

I've been learning programming own my for a couple of years mainly using python, and
I've created a tetris-like command line game using Python's Curses library.
The game seems to function as intended; but I lack experience writing object oriented code.
So, I would like feedback about the code's structure, and assuming the structure is ok, the code's style.

```
from copy import deepcopy
import time
import curses
import random


class TetrisPiece:
    def __init__(self, indices, center_of_rotation, color):
        self.indices = indices
        self.center_of_rotation = center_of_rotation
        self.last_move_overlap = False
        self.color = color


class TetrisBoard:
    def __init__(self, num_rows, num_columns):
        self.num_rows = num_rows
        self.num_columns = num_columns

        self.array = [[0] * self.num_columns for _ in range(self.num_rows)]
        self.active_piece = None

    def in_bounds(self, temp_active_piece_indices):
        return all(0 <= i < self.num_rows and 0 <= j < self.num_columns
                   for i, j in temp_active_piece_indices)

    def no_overlap(self, temp_active_piece_indices):
        return all(self.array[i][j] == 0 for i, j in
                   set(temp_active_piece_indices) - set(self.active_piece.indices))

    def add_piece(self, piece):
        # try to place Piece near top center of board
        new_active_piece_indices = [(i, j + int(self.num_columns / 2) - 1)
                                    for i, j in piece.indices]

        if all(self.array[i][j] == 0 for i, j in new_active_piece_indices):
            self.active_piece = piece
            self.update_array(new_active_piece_indices)
            piece.indices = new_active_piece_indices
            piece.center_of_rotation[1] += int(self.num_columns / 2) - 1
            piece.last_move_overlap = False
        else:
            piece.last_move_overlap = True

    def rotate_active_piece(self):
        # rotates active piece indices 90 degrees counter clockwise about it's
        # center of a rotation

        x, y = self.active_piece.center_of_rotation

        # this translates the active piece so that it's center is
        # the origin, then rotates each point in indices about the origin,
        # then translates the piece so that it's center is at it's
        # original position
        temp_active_piece_indices = [(int(-j + y + x), int(i - x + y))
                                     for i, j in self.active_piece.indices]

        if (self.in_bounds(temp_active_piece_indices)
                and self.no_overlap(temp_active_piece_indices)):
            self.update_array(temp_active_piece_indices)
            self.active_piece.indices = temp_active_piece_indices

    def translate_active_piece(self, direction):
        if direction == 'right':
            x, y = 0, 1
        elif direction == 'left':
            x, y = 0, -1
        elif direction == 'down':
            x, y = 1, 0

        temp_active_piece_indices = [(i + x, j + y)
                                     for i, j in self.active_piece.indices]
        if (self.in_bounds(temp_active_piece_indices)
                and self.no_overlap(temp_active_piece_indices)):
            self.update_array(temp_active_piece_indices)
            self.active_piece.indices = temp_active_piece_indices
            self.active_piece.center_of_rotation[0] += x
            self.active_piece.center_of_rotation[1] += y

            self.active_piece.last_move_overlap = False

        elif (self.in_bounds(temp_active_piece_indices)
              and not self.no_overlap(temp_active_piece_indices)):
            self.active_piece.last_move_overlap = True

        # this is necessary to tell when a piece hits the bottom of the
        # board
        elif not self.in_bounds(temp_active_piece_indices) and direction == 'down':
            self.active_piece.last_move_overlap = True

    def update_array(self, new_indices):
        for i, j in self.active_piece.indices:
            self.array[i][j] = 0
        for i, j in new_indices:
            self.array[i][j] = self.active_piece.color


class CursesWindow:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.window = None

    def update(self):
        pass

    def refresh(self):
        self.window.refresh()

    def addstr(self, y, x, string):
        self.window.addstr(y, x, string)


class BoardWindow(CursesWindow):
    def __init__(self, game):
        CursesWindow.__init__(self, game)

        # the window's border adds two extra rows and two extra columns
        self.num_rows = game.board.num_rows + 2
        self.num_columns = game.board.num_columns + 2

        self.window = curses.newwin(
            self.num_rows,
            self.num_columns
        )

        self.window.border('*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*')
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        # only update the interior of the window
        for i in range(self.num_rows - 2):
            for j in range(self.num_columns - 2):
                if self.game.board.array[i][j] != 0:
                    self.window.addstr(
                        i + 1,
                        j + 1,
                        '1',
                        curses.color_pair(self.game.board.array[i][j])
                    )
                else:
                    self.window.addstr(i + 1, j + 1, '.')
        self.window.refresh()

    def keypad(self, flag):
        self.window.keypad(flag)

    def nodelay(self, flag):
        self.window.nodelay(flag)

    def getch(self):
        return self.window.getch()


class ScoreWindow(CursesWindow):
    def __init__(self, game, board_window):
        CursesWindow.__init__(self, game)
        self.num_items_to_display = 3

        # the window's border adds two extra rows
        self.num_rows = self.num_items_to_display + 2

        # 6 digits for the string 'score:' + max_num_score_digits + 2 for border
        self.num_columns = 6 + game.max_num_score_digits + 2

        self.window = curses.newwin(
            self.num_rows,
            self.num_columns,
            0,
            board_window.num_columns + 1
        )

        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.window.erase()
        self.window.border('*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*')
        self.window.addstr(1, 1, f'Score:{self.game.score}')
        self.window.addstr(2, 1, f'Lines:{self.game.lines_completed}')
        self.window.addstr(3, 1, f'Level:{self.game.level}')
        self.window.refresh()


class PiecePreviewWindow(CursesWindow):
    def __init__(self, game, board_window, score_window):
        CursesWindow.__init__(self, game)

        # the window's border adds two extra rows and two extra columns
        self.num_rows = game.max_piece_length + 2
        self.num_columns = game.max_piece_length + 2

        self.window = curses.newwin(
            self.num_rows,
            self.num_columns,
            score_window.num_rows,
            board_window.num_columns + 1
        )

        self.window.border('*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*')
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.window.erase()

        # only update the interior of the window
        for i in range(self.num_rows - 2):
            for j in range(self.num_columns - 2):
                if (i, j) in self.game.next_piece.indices:
                    self.window.addstr(
                        i + 1,
                        j + 1,
                        '1',
                        curses.color_pair(self.game.next_piece.color)
                    )

        self.window.refresh()


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game

        curses.initscr()
        curses.start_color()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        curses.curs_set(0)

        curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
        curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
        curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_YELLOW, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
        curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_BLUE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
        curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
        curses.init_pair(6, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
        curses.init_pair(7, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

        self.board_window = BoardWindow(game)
        self.score_window = ScoreWindow(game, self.board_window)
        self.piece_preview_window = PiecePreviewWindow(game, self.board_window,
                                                       self.score_window)

        self.board_window.keypad(True)
        self.board_window.nodelay(True)


class Game:
    def __init__(self, board_num_rows, board_num_columns):
        self.board = TetrisBoard(board_num_rows, board_num_columns)

        self.score = 0
        self.max_num_score_digits = 8
        self.lines_completed = 0
        self.level = 0

        self.SPACE_KEY_VALUE = 32

        # approximate frame rate
        self.frame_rate = 60

        self.pieces = [
            TetrisPiece([(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)], [1.5, 1.5], 1),  # I
            TetrisPiece([(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [1, 1], 2),  # J
            TetrisPiece([(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)], [1, 1], 3),  # L
            TetrisPiece([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)], [.5, .5], 4),  # O
            TetrisPiece([(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [1, 1], 5),  # S
            TetrisPiece([(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1)], [1, 1], 6),  # T
            TetrisPiece([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)], [1, 1], 7)  # Z
        ]

        self.max_piece_length = 4
        
        self.next_piece = deepcopy(random.choice(self.pieces))

        self.GUI = GUI(self)

    def points(self, number_of_lines):
        coefficients = [0, 40, 100, 300, 1200]
        return coefficients[number_of_lines] * (self.level + 1)

    def main_loop(self):
        self.board.add_piece(self.next_piece)
        self.next_piece = deepcopy(random.choice(self.pieces))
        self.GUI.piece_preview_window.update()

        loop_count = 0
        while True:
            keyboard_input = self.GUI.board_window.getch()

            loop_count += 1

            force_move = (loop_count % max(self.frame_rate - self.level, 1) == 0)
            hard_drop = (keyboard_input == self.SPACE_KEY_VALUE)
            if force_move or hard_drop:
                if hard_drop:
                    while not self.board.active_piece.last_move_overlap:
                        self.board.translate_active_piece('down')

                    self.GUI.board_window.update()
                    time.sleep(.5)

                elif force_move:
                    self.board.translate_active_piece('down')

                if self.board.active_piece.last_move_overlap:
                    # try to clear lines one at a time starting from the top of
                    # the screen
                    line_count = 0
                    for row_number, row in enumerate(self.board.array):
                        if all(row):
                            # highlight row to be deleted
                            # add 1 to row_number because of board_window's border
                            self.GUI.board_window.addstr(
                                row_number + 1, 1, '=' * self.board.num_columns
                            )

                            self.GUI.board_window.refresh()
                            time.sleep(.5)

                            # delete row
                            del self.board.array[row_number]
                            self.board.array.insert(0, [0] * self.board.num_columns)

                            self.GUI.board_window.update()
                            time.sleep(.5)

                            line_count += 1

                    self.score += self.points(line_count)
                    self.lines_completed += line_count
                    self.level = self.lines_completed // 2

                    # Basically, reset the game to prevent the strings
                    # corresponding to the score, lines_completed, or level
                    # variables from exceeding the dimensions the score_window
                    if len(str(self.score)) > self.max_num_score_digits:
                        self.score = 0
                        self.level = 0
                        self.lines_completed = 0

                    self.GUI.score_window.update()

                    # try to add nextPiece to Board
                    self.board.add_piece(self.next_piece)

                    # if unsuccessful, gameover
                    if self.next_piece.last_move_overlap:
                        break

                    self.next_piece = deepcopy(random.choice(self.pieces))
                    self.GUI.piece_preview_window.update()

            else:
                if keyboard_input == ord('w'):
                    self.board.rotate_active_piece()
                if keyboard_input == ord('d'):
                    self.board.translate_active_piece('right')
                if keyboard_input == ord('s'):
                    self.board.translate_active_piece('down')
                if keyboard_input == ord('a'):
                    self.board.translate_active_piece('left')
                # exit game
                if keyboard_input == ord('e'):
                    break

            self.GUI.board_window.update()

            # delay after a rotation
            if keyboard_input == ord('w'):
                time.sleep(.25)

            time.sleep(1 / self.frame_rate)

        # Reset terminal window before exiting the game.
        curses.nocbreak()
        self.GUI.board_window.keypad(False)
        self.GUI.board_window.nodelay(False)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()
        curses.curs_set(1)

        print('Game Over')
        exit()


# Run the game
game = Game(board_num_rows=16, board_num_columns=10)
game.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it looks structured, using good names, split up into functions etc. Those are good things.

I have some comments but remember these are my opinions, I can't say that it's right or wrong and I won't refer to any standard or code style.

### 1

```
def in_bounds(self, temp_active_piece_indices):
    return all(0 <= i < self.num_rows and 0 <= j < self.num_columns
               for i, j in temp_active_piece_indices)
```

This piece of code is very short and compact. Few lines, and using Python things like double list comprehension. It gets a lot done with few bytes of code.

I find it hard to read though and I wouldn't want to cooperate with you on this project if you wrote a lot of code like this, because I would have to spend so much time untangling and trying to understand what something does, before modifying or extending it. And if it needs to be modified, it might need to be completely rewritten.

A suggestion for how to write it differently, that I find easier to understand (again, this is subjective of course).

```
def in_bounds(self, x, y):
    return x >= 0 and x < self.num_columns and y >= 0 and y < self.num_rows
```

This function only handles one piece and it takes the coordinates in directly, it doesn't "care" what those coordinates represents (a piece, but could now be used for anything else too).

I think using `x` and `y` is natural since the rows and columns function as coordinates in a tetris game. This is more specific than `i` and `j` which are often used as iterators for any inner loop, which doesn't necessarily or naturally relate to coordinates.

Also, I'm looking at each case one at a time, no need to use `all` and "remember" the pieces simultaneously. This is the most important change to make it readable and piece-by-piece easy to understand.

When calling the function from the outside, it now makes sense to use `all`.

`if all([in_bounds(x,y) for (y,x) in pieces]):`

### 2

```
def translate_active_piece(self, direction):
    if direction == 'right':
        x, y = 0, 1
    elif direction == 'left':
        x, y = 0, -1
    elif direction == 'down':
        x, y = 1, 0
```

This is the opposite. No one will ever misunderstand this code or have to look more than a few seconds to understand it. I prefer code like this when I review something. It could be rewritten and convoluted to be much shorter, but that's not necessary and it wouldn't make it easier to work with.

If you had more options though, let's say 4 or more, I would use a dict to reduce the repetition of `if` `elif` and `x,y=`

### 3

```
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_YELLOW, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_BLUE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(6, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(7, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
```

Too much repetition here. This can be improved.

```
colors = [curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_YELLOW, ...]
for i, x in enumerate(colors, start=1):
    curses.init_pair(i, x, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Related to your first point, did you find the no_overlap method of the TetrisBoard class difficult to read as well?

Comment: Yes. same problem with that one. Even worse, I think.

Comment: I added a suggestion for a different way to do #1